# Flutter - OAuth Azure AD - Authentication

Tags: flutter, dart

Has anyone done OAuth authentication to Azure Active Directory (B2C)?
I used the plugin

I have a problem after authentication to return to the app page.
The authentication screen does not close and does not return to the app.

```
Future<void> _logIn() async {
try {
  final AuthorizationTokenResponse result =
      await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
    AuthorizationTokenRequest(
      _clientId,
      _redirectUrl,
      serviceConfiguration:
          AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(_authorizeUrl, _tokenUrl),
      scopes: _scopes,
    ),
  );
  if (result != null) {
    _processAuthTokenResponse(result);
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

Tks, Luciano